# Superscript in citation and bibliography (using interact document class)

Tags: citing, natbib, superscripts, cite-package

I am using a template for a journal paper (Taylor & Francis), it has `\documentclass[]{interact}`. I want to use the superscript citation as shown in the next figure:

[image]

I am using also the following packages:

- `\usepackage[superscript,biblabel]{cite}`
- `\usepackage[super]{natbib}`
- `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}`

The problem is, the superscript citations are not generated automatically after the punctuation (points, commas, ...). Also, when there are successive references, it shows all their numbers (1;2;3;4 as shown in the next figure) but I want it like this way `1-4`

[image]

I am using `\usepackage[super]{natbib}` to show superscript references in bibliography as shown hereafter:

[image]

The command `\cite{}` is used in the text.

How to adjust the citation ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using both the `cite` and the `natbib` packages, or just one. Please clarify.

Comment: Please also clarify what is meant by "the superscript citations are not generated automatically after the punctuation [marks]". In particular, do please reveal how you use `\cite` instructions at present.

Comment: @Mico, yes, I am using both. The `natbib` is used to show superscript references in the bibliography section. The `\cite{}` command is used to cite references from bibtex file.

Comment: A general remark: The `cite` and `natbib` citation packages should *never* be used simultaneously in a LaTeX document. Use one or the other package, *but not both*. Please do provide one ore more examples of how you use `\cite` instructions, so that we may better understand the expression "the superscript citations are not generated automatically after the punctuation".

Comment: @Mico, to be clear, I want my citations according to the 1st image, and the numbering style in the bibliography section according to the 3rd image, that's all.

Comment: To be clear: You have already stated, very clearly, what you are trying to achieve. What you have *not* done so far is to state what you've been *doing*. All you've told is that something isn't working quite right; at least, that's what the expression "superscript citations are not generated automatically after the punctuation" would appear to indicate. Unless you provide some more information as to what exactly you're doing, it's not likely that anybody can come up with a diagnosis of what's causing the problem, let alone come up with a cure.

Comment: Thank you @Mico. As you said before, `cite` and `natbib` don't work together, and this was the problem. I removed `natbib` and everythings work.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP's issue was identified and fixed in the comments.